# Recommended method for querying related data from JSON/REST calls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I have two related datasources that I retrieve via REST to create JSON outputs. One is a list of categories, and the second is a list of articles. A category may contain many articles.

I want to query articles by the category. As an example, get a count of all the articles by category. What is the best/recommended approach for this? In the jQuery world, I could nest AJAX calls and pass along a variable from the first AJAX call.

Here are my services:

```
// Categories
pfcServices.factory('pfcArticleCategories', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/tables/categories', {},
    {
        'update': { method: 'PATCH' }
    }
    );
}]);   

// All Articles
pfcServices.factory('pfcArticles', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles', {},
    {
        'update': { method: 'PATCH' }
    }
    );
}]);
```

Here are some controllers:

```
// Retrive categories
pfcControllers.controller('pfcCategoriesCtrl', ['$scope', 'pfcArticleCategories', function ($scope, pfcArticleCategories) {
$scope.categories = pfcArticleCategories.query();
}]);

// All Articles for Counts, Large Queries, etc.
pfcControllers.controller('pfcArticlesCtrl', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, pfcArticles) {
$scope.articles = pfcArticles.query();
}]);
```

Would something like a nested function in the 'pfcArticlesCtrl' work? I have a feeling this is not the recommended approach. Example:

```
pfcControllers.controller('pfcArticlesCtrl', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', 'pfcArticleCategories', function ($scope, pfcArticles, pfcArticleCategories) {
$scope.categories = pfcArticleCategories.query();    
$scope.articles = pfcArticles.query();
var val = [];

angular.forEach(categories, function (value, key) {
    var catid = value.catid

    angular.forEach(articles, function (v, k) {
        if (value.articlecategoryid == catid) {
        // count number of articles and psuh them to an array of val to be referenced by $scope.count using ng-repeat
        }
    }, val);
}

$scope.count = val;

}]);
```